# associative arrays php to sql

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to insert data from that array into my database with sql.

```
foreach ($array as $row){
    mysql_query($link,"INSERT INTO table (name, surname) VALUES('"$array[0][name]"', '"$array[0][surname]"')}
```

Comment: [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: You have an extra " in `, '"$someArray[brand_name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling object instead of array. You should call row['name'] instead of $array['name'].

```
foreach ($array as $row){
    mysql_query($link,"INSERT INTO table (name, surname) VALUES('$row[name]', '"$row[surname]'"); 
};
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: True. I normally use PDO with parameter binding. For this instance I just gave the visible solution. ;-)

Comment: There is an additional quotation mark before $row[brand_name]. check that

Comment: Try This :   foreach ($someArray as $row){
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO dresses (name, brand_name, price, linke_url, offer) VALUES('$row[name]', '$row[brand_name]', '$row[price]', '$row[link_url]', '$row[offer]')"); 
};

Comment: it is fine. because inside of foreach you can access each array directly. as an example in first loop you can access first array. Second loop second array like that. so that is not the issue. something wrong with your sql. check for not nulluble columns left on your db table (not inserting column).

Comment: use below code and show me output

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO dresses (name, brand_name, price, linke_url, offer) VALUES('$row[name]', '$row[brand_name]', '$row[price]', '$row[link_url]', '$row[offer]')"); echo $result. '<br>';